# Problems drawing a bitmap on a layout

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, nullpointerexception, mutable

I create the Layout programatically in onCreate:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myView = new MyView(SketchActivity.this, layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight());

            layout2.addView(myView);
            layout2.bringToFront();

        }
    }, 50);
```

The View where i create the (mutable?) bitmap:

```
public MyView(Context c, int width, int height) {
        super(c);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        int w = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
        int h = display.getHeight();
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);

        // setting paint
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAlpha(0);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        // getting image from resources
        Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smoke);

        // converting image bitmap into mutable bitmap

        bitmap = bm.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap); // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

My onDraw function:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
```

OnTouchEvent:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        r = 20;
        // Atlast invalidate canvas
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
```

No LogCat Errors
The problem is in myView. when i create the bitmap bitmap = bm.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888); If i put instead of w,h(width and height of screen) a small number Example: bitmap = bm.createBitmap(20, 20, Config.ARGB_8888); it creates a tiny picture. But if I put w and h, then instead of drawing on all the layout, it only draws on a small part. (even if i try: bitmap = bm.createBitmap(800, 1080, Config.ARGB_8888); it still draws on a small part, instead of all the screen. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're recycling your `Bitmap` somwhere in the code. There is a problem.

Yes, you should `recycle` it, but it's always a bit risky.

**EDIT**

Looks like you're drawing onto `Bitmap`. If it's not what you're trying to do, then you shouldn't call `onDraw` manually. Instead call `invalidate()` when you want to redraw your view.

Comment: ok, i managed to escape the errors, but still my bitmap does not appear on the layout, i edited the code

Comment: But i don't call onDraw manually, but i see your point, i forgot to call invalidate. Called it, but still no luck, am i doing this right? (code edited (again))

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `Options` data like this:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.isMutable = true; // works from api 11

mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smoke, options);
```

Comment: It has to be Api 8 (2.2). And i managed to make it mutable, no errors, but still it does not show the picture on my layout

Comment: @rosualin then the problem is your layout. try just drawing a blue color and make it be seen on the screen, after this you will be able to see the image too. Also play with the path and the paint

Comment: i have a layout with a picture on it. and an empty layout over it (child) So i try to put another picture on the second layout to show. So that in the future, when i click somewhere, the app to delete that part where i clicked of the picture. This is how i thought it , but if you know how to do this in a simpler, or classy way, please help