# How to draw image over preexisting layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I've got a space game, but now I need to spawn enemy spaceships over the top of my preexisting content_layout.xml (which has things like a star background). I don't know where to start because I'm not using ImageViews like I did for my spaceship because I want to spawn them continuously.

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191317/problems-drawing-a-bitmap-on-a-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:
 https://android--code.blogspot.co.il/2015/08/android-imageview-programmatically.html

Or this:
[Problems drawing a bitmap on a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191317/problems-drawing-a-bitmap-on-a-layout)